# How to Store data to NSUserDefaults in prepareForSeque

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to do the following: 
In settings scene change settings and when I press the "back" arrow, the changed data should be stored. 
I assumed it should be done in the `prepareForSeque` method, as seen below:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString* session_port = self.session_port.text;
    NSString* session_address = self.session_address.text;
    NSString* keep_alive_interval = self.session_keep_alive_interval.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:session_port forKey:@"sessionPort"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:session_address forKey:@"sesssionAddress"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:keep_alive_interval forKey:@"keepAliveInterval"];
}
```

However it does not seem to work as when I enter the settings window again, the data is still the standard data.

Can someone give me a hint in the right direction?

I load the data in the settings view like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.session_address.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"sesssionAddress"];
    self.session_port.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"sessionPort"];
    self.session_keep_alive_interval.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"keepAliveInterval"];

}
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Comment: change the store options to on inside the event listener

Comment: `Back` button will not call `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Comment: So what should I do instead ?

Comment: Hard to guess with the given info. But you can always use `delegate pattern` to send back data to the previous view controller.

Comment: may be you have not used values in userDefaults properly while you again enters in settings scene, so add more code and details.

Comment: Are you using `NSUserDefaults` to pass data between different parts of your app?

Comment: @Droppy I am using it to store data both between different parts of the application, but also for future use. It is not throw away data

Comment: Well it is thrown away as it's being overwritten every time you enter that method.  There is no need to store stuff in `NSUserDefaults` every second; learn how to pass data correctly between different view controllers.

Comment: @Droppy please elaborate on that, because I need to store it even if the application is shutdown. So what do you think I should do instead ?

Comment: I should add that I do not immediately go to a view where the data will be used

Comment: Remove it completely and get your navigation working without it.  Then add it back in later, where the data can be saved/loaded at a more appropriate time.

Comment: @Droppy okay will try that thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead for during the above in `prepareForSeque` it can be done in `viewWillDisappear` as presented below:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSString* session_port = self.session_port.text;
    NSString* session_address = self.session_address.text;
    NSString* keep_alive_interval = self.session_keep_alive_interval.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:session_port forKey:@"sessionPort"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:session_address forKey:@"sesssionAddress"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:keep_alive_interval forKey:@"keepAliveInterval"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

However this is not an optimal solution as NSUserDefaults are access every time you change the settings. one should use another means of propagating the change through out the application and then store the data when the applications is closed.